# mongo - how to query a nested json

Tags: mongodb

I am a complete mongo newbie. I am using mongo hub for mac. I need to query the for following json -

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "abcd" ),
"className" : "com.myUser",
"reg" : 12345,
"test" : [ 
{ "className" : "com.abc",
  "testid" : "pqrs" } ] }
```

and find records where testid is pqrs. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can type `{'test.testid': 'pqrs'}` in the query field of Mongo Hub.

Comment: How to query based on _id too ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `test` is an array. If you are expecting multiple values in array you can do -

```
"test": { 
    "$elemMatch": {
        "testid": "pqrs",
    }
}
```